# присвоение меток в БД

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, как будет правильно присвоить для файла метки в БД?
Например, есть запись файла в БД:
`id = 1, name = filename2015, extension = mp4, hash = pv52puegod6k4nl6d7cirraq93`
для него пользователь устанавливает метки: `отдых, египет, 2015`
Мне потребуется создать таблицу меток:
`отдых  = 3
египет  = 4
2015    = 5`
и отдельную таблицу где буду их связывать, то есть всего 3 таблицы: файлы, метки, связь между первыми двумя:
`1 = 3
1 = 4
1 = 5`
где 1 - это id файла, а 3,4,5 - это id меток

Comment: И чем вас такое решение не устраивает?

Comment: @BOPOH дело в том, что еще можно прямо в таблице файлов писать метки. Для файла создать поле, в которое будут писаться id меток через двоеточие, к примеру: `3:4:5`, потом парсить и уже по этим id получать названия меток. Т.е. запрос данных о файле, парсинг, и запрос названия меток. Из примера в вопросе: запрос данных о файле, поосле, по id файла, получаю все связанные метки с ним, и далее данные о метках (о названии меток). Но, так понимаю, поиск при этом, по меткам, невозможен. Или?

Comment: @Plush: подобная возможность есть в PostgreSQL  - тип данных array ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html , http://blog.miralita.me/?p=40)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да - это правильное решение.

```
table object {
  id int autoincrement,
  somefilelds,
  primary key(id) 
}

table tags {
  id int autoincrement,
  tag varchar,
  primary key(id) 
}

table object_tag_relations {
  id int autoincrement,
  object_id int,
  tag_id int,
  index object_idx(object_id),
  index tag_idx(tag_id),
}
```